# Spark time series data generation

Tags: scala, time, apache-spark, series

I am trying to generate time series data in Spark and Scala. I have the following data in DataFrame which is hourly data

```
sid|date                             |count
200|2016-04-30T18:00:00:00+00:00     | 10
200 |2016-04-30T21:00:00:00+00:00    | 5
```

I want to generate time series data for the last 2 days hourly by taking the max time from the input. In my case the series data should start from 2016-04-30T21:00:00:00+00:00 and generate hourly data.Any hour without data then it should put the count as null. Sample output as follows

```
id|sid|date                          |count
1 |200|2016-04-28T22:00:00:00+00:00  |
2 |200|2016-04-28T23:00:00:00+00:00  |
3 |200|2016-04-29T00:00:00:00+00:00  |
--------------------------------------
45|200|2016-04-30T18:00:00:00+00:00  |10
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
48|200|2016-04-30T21:00:00:00+00:00  |5
```

Thanks,

Comment: Just generate the continuous time data separately in the range you want, then join this with the dataframe that has the counts. Use an outer join.

Comment: thanks! is there any function which can use to generate continues time data from a given time?

Comment: Just use the basic Java calendar stuff. I'd look it up and write a proper answer if I had time, but I don't, sorry.